# How can a specific containerFactory be assigned to a particular @RabbitListener programmatically and dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

There is a `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` for every `@RabbitListener`. Default is used unless otherwise specified in the annotation.

It is also possible to change the default with `rabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.setContainerFactoryBeanName()`.

I am looking for a way to set (or even override if already set via the original annotation) a **different** `ContainerFactory` **for each** `@RabbitListener` in an app (The `ContainerFactory` will be set according to the queue name to be listened to)

*Bonus question*: How to set (in such a case) the `ContainerFactory` bean itself, rather than setting the name of the bean (as with `setContainerFactoryBeanName` above).

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the factory bean name on the `@RabbitListener` annotation:

```java
/**
 * The bean name of the
 * {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory} to
 * use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>
 * If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any. If a SpEL
 * expression is provided ({@code #{...}}), the expression can either evaluate to a
 * container factory instance or a bean name.
 * @return the
 * {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

Comment: Thank you, Gary. Although I'm aware of this option, I would like to do it *programmatically and dynamically* instead of hardcoding it directly into the annotation.

Comment: It's not currently possible; the endpoint is registered immediately after resolving the factory's bean name; I see a couple of options; we could make `resolveContainerFactory` protected so you could subclass the BPP and override the default BPP bean definition, or we could move the registration to a new method that is called after `processListener`.

Comment: Sounds like you need something like a  `DelegatingRabbitListenerContainerFactory`, which would decide to what to call by the provided `RabbitListenerEndpoint`, which you can cast to the `AbstractRabbitListenerEndpoint` and check its `getQueueNames()` for your purpose.

Comment: However, as the javadoc says, the annotation can be a SpEL expression - you can invoke any Java code from there `#{@someBean.getContainerFactoryFor(${some.queue})}`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I can't access the class which is annotated with the `@RabbitListener`, so I need to control it from another (config?) class.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on GitHub and I will refactor the BPP to make it easier to extend for cases like this.